# jquery multiple different id with a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use multiple different id with a variable of ID value?
It don't show any error or output

```
function show_div(id)
{
    $("#edit_li"+id, "#save_li"+id).show();
}
```

Comment: you can debug using console.log

Answer (score 2):

```
function show_div(id)
{
    $("#edit_tag"+id+",#save_li"+id).show();
}
```

The variable to be placed between + , while using within string.

Answer (score 1):

Comma separate multi-selector, not as parameter

```
function show_div(id)
{
    $("#edit_tag"+id+ ",#save_li"+id).show();
    //               --^--
}
```

REF : **[Multiple-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `,` in selector as well as the comma outside mean you have two parameters in the selector instead of separating ids in selector.

```
$("#edit_tag"+id  ", #save_li"+id).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Always append and prepend your variables with `+` when they are in a string

```
function show_div(id)
    {
        $("#edit_tag"+id+",#save_li"+id).show();
    }
```